# How to determine if a website is installed in IIS7 with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis-7, tfsbuild

I'm pretty new to powershell, and I'm trying to automate the removal of a prior version of a website and addition of the newer version as a part of a TFS 2010 Build Template (Windows Workflow 4.0). Is it possible to see if a website or web app pool exists in IIS7 with powershell? I've tried running the following command:

```
import-module WebAdministration
Get-Website -Name "Default Web Site"
```

The output lists all of the websites installed on the box, not just the default web site.

```
Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Default Web Site 1    Started    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:
                                                                net.tcp 808:*
                                                                net.pipe *
                                                                net.msmq localhost
                                                                msmq.formatname localhost 
MyWebsite1       2    Started    C:\inetpub\MyWebsite1          http *:80:mywebsite1.com
MyWebsite2       3    Started    C:\inetpub\MyWebsite2          http *:80:mywebsite2.com
```

If I try to run the command without the "-Name" parameter, the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just noticed the same behavior.  Seems like its not working as expected.  However, you can roll your own:

```
get-website | where-object { $_.name -eq 'MyWebsite1' }
```

That just pipes the list returned by **get-website** to the **where-object** cmdlet and just return that single object.

If your new to PowerShell, I can't recommend [Master PowerShell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/default.aspx) enough.

Comment: good answer, +, +1 for link to Master Powershell. That looks awesome. Thanks!

Comment: The other answer didn't work for me, but this did. I just ran `if ($(Get-Website | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'sitename' }) -eq $null)` and it worked.

Answer (score 51):

You can use Test-Path for both checking web sites & application pools:

```
Import-Module webadministration
$alias = "MyWebSite1"
$IISPath = "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\$alias"

if (Test-Path $IISPath) { Write-Host "$alias exists." }

$IISPath = "IIS:\AppPools"
cd $IISPath
if (Test-Path ".\MyAppPool") { Write-Host "MyAppPool exists." }
```

Comment: I really wish I could mark two answers because this was helpful as well because it gave me another part of the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: Where is this IIS:\Sites path?

Comment: That's a "virtual" path created by the IIS PowerShell provider.

Comment: Why does the script need to cd to IIS:\AppPools?

Comment: You don't *need* to. This was just to illustrate the capabilities of the IIS PowerShell provider.

Comment: Test-Path IIS:\ alawys returns false for me

Comment: @SZT I had to include 'import-module webadministration' and run script as administrator before mine would work